# Add class to parent that has a specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the class `.hidden` to the parent when I click on a `.input` class when the parent of that `.input` class has a child `.delete`. Otherwise, remove the parent instead of just hiding it. The problem is that it always adds the `.hidden` class to the parent, no matter what.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <input class='input' type='text'>
    <input class='input delete' type='text'>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <input class='input' type='text'>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.input').on('click', function() {

    var element = $(this);

    if (element.parent().has('.delete')) {
            element.parent().addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            element.parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. But maybe you want to use `hasClass()` instead?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls88xxds/

Comment: Use `hasClass()` or `is()` which return boolean. `.has()` filters results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.has()` doesn't return true/false, it selects. Change the if to:

```
if (element.parent().has('.delete').length) {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ur56eky/)**

Comment: Or use `.is()` which does what OP expected `.has()` to

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case

```
   element.parent().has('.delete')
```

returns a jQuery object which will have have either one or zero DOM elements in it. Used in an 'if' statement this will evaluate to true, thus you will never get the else case.

Instead use

```
   element.parent().has('.delete').length
```

which will return 0 or 1. The zero will evaluate to false in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the parent has a child element with the `.delete` class, then you can to change your code to this:

```
$('.input').on('click', function() {

    var element = $(this);

    if (element.parent().children('.delete').length > 0) {
            element.parent().addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            element.parent().remove();
    }
});
```